# Socket Exception thrown on localhost, but not over network?

Tags: java, sockets, exception, crash, localhost

I've got a Client-Server program. This is the client loop:

```
while ((msg = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(msg);
                //handle communication
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //handle server crash
        }
```

When I connect via localhost, everything is working fine: Once I shut the server down, I get an exception client-side. But as soon as I connect via the local network and run the server on another pc, I don't get that exception anymore, neither if I kill the process nor if I plug the cable of the server pc. How can that be? I also tried having a Thread which checks socket.isClosed(), but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong, and why is it working via the localhost!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP works such that connection state is not being frequently synchronized between parties when the connection is idle. This is a logical choice because synchronization is pure traffic overhead. When you suddenly break the communication channel, the other side simply sits idle thinking nothing happened.

On the other hand, when you are on "localhost", that means you are actually on the loopback adapter, and no synchronization over the wire is needed. The other end is immediately notified of the channel breakdown.

Comment: Ah okay thank you. But a strange thing I noticed is that it works running the server on my Windows PC, but it does not work when I host it on my Raspberry PI. (Now I tested it with an Android application -> connecting to the windows pc with a real phone over the local network worked - I got the exception; connecting to the RaspPI didn't). And is there any other way to get the client notificated about a server shutdown?

Comment: Normally the server process will at least do normal TCP socket cleanup, sending a RST packet. This should be enough for the client side to notice.

Comment: Is there a way to listen to that RST packet in Java?

Comment: AFAIK, if you are in the middle of a blocking read on an `InputStream` or its derivative, you'll get an `IOException: connection reset by peer` as soon as the underlying I/O layers take note of the packet.

Comment: I just did another test: I changed the port forwarding settings and ran the server on my windows pc. I then connected via my app with 3G and when I shut the server down, it worked. Do you have any idea why it does not work with the linux server?

Comment: No, sorry. It's probably not as simple as "doesn't work on Linux", there must be some specific subtlety.

Comment: Maybe the linux server is not as fast as the windows pc...? I got no clue. Is there a difference whether I use ctrl + c(Linux) or terminate the process in NetBeans (Windows PC)?